# Printing all elements of a list on the same line separated by a space

Tags: python

I'm unable to print all the elements of the list in the same line.

For `n = 5`, I was expecting the output

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

but instead I got

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: What is the code you used to try and accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem.

```
n = int(input("Enter the value of n: "))
l = []
for i in range(n):
    l.append(i+1)
print("Elements of the list are:", end=" ")
for i in l:
    print(i, end=" ")
```